Deploy static files to cloudflare pages via API
Inside my node js project I need to add functionalitty for deploying some static files to Cloudflare. Currently for testing purposes, but it will become more complicated in future. For now I need want to trigger some endpoint and deploy static html file (which located directly in folder inside project) to cloudfare project. I've alredy created the project and API KEY.
Inside my CloudflareService I'm creating manifest object, fill it with hash and size of my index.html file. Then I zip my file and send it to Cloudflare. On Cloudflare UI I see that deployment if successful, in View details I see that 1 files uploaded, index.html, everything looks fine, but the site itself doesn't work, HTTP ERROR 500
I'm saving zip file to the same directory where my index.html located to check if zip archive properly created. It does, I even tried to mannually deploy it to my project, and it worked just fine.
Also I checked manual and via API deployments details via curl request, the key difference is that manual deployment has this files object
    "files": {
      "/index.html": "d7d1eb93bwaecfb11d651c5c431c5265"
    }

And in deployment via API
    "files": {
      "/index.html": ""
    }

Any help aprreciated, thanks.
This is my CloudflareService.js file
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import axios from 'axios';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { env } from '../lib/env';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import FormData from 'form-data'; // Import form-data for Node.js
import archiver from 'archiver'; // Library to create ZIP files

class CloudflareService {
  constructor() {
    this.accountId = env.CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID; // Access environment variable
    this.apiToken = env.CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN;   // Access environment variable
    this.projectName = env.CLOUDFLARE_PROJECT_NAME; // Access environment variable
    this.baseURL = `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/${this.accountId}/pages/projects/${this.projectName}/deployments`;
  }

  // Helper function to get file hash and size
  getFileHashAndSize(filePath) {
    const stats = fs.statSync(filePath); // Get the file stats (size)
    const fileSize = stats.size;

    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath); // Read the file synchronously
    hash.update(fileBuffer);
    const fileHash = hash.digest('hex'); // Convert to hexadecimal format

    return { hash: fileHash, size: fileSize };
  }

  // Creates a ZIP file containing the specified file
  async createZipFile(filePath) {
    const zipPath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), 'deployment.zip');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const output = fs.createWriteStream(zipPath);
      const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });

      output.on('close', () => resolve(zipPath));
      archive.on('error', (err) => reject(err));

      archive.pipe(output);
      archive.file(filePath, { name: 'index.html' }); // Add the file to the ZIP as "index.html"
      archive.finalize();
    });
  }

  // Main deployment method for a single file
  async deployLocalFile(filePath) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
      throw new Error(`File not found: ${filePath}`);
    }

    const zipFilePath = await this.createZipFile(filePath); // Save ZIP in the same directory
    const { hash, size } = this.getFileHashAndSize(filePath);

    const manifest = {
      "/index.html": {
        hash: hash,
        size: size,
      },
    };

    const zipStream = fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath);

    // Deploy to Cloudflare
    const result = await this.deployToCloudflare(zipStream, manifest);

    // Leave the ZIP file in place for inspection
    console.log(`ZIP file created at: ${zipFilePath}`);
    return result;
  }

  // Handles communication with the Cloudflare API
  async deployToCloudflare(fileStream, manifest) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fileStream, 'deployment.zip'); // Add the ZIP file to the form
    form.append('manifest', JSON.stringify(manifest)); // Add the manifest

    try {
      // Debugging: Log manifest before sending
      console.log('Manifest being sent:', JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2));

      const response = await axios.post(this.baseURL, form, {
        headers: {
          ...form.getHeaders(),
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.apiToken}`,
        },
      });

      // Debugging: Log response for additional insights
      console.log('Response from Cloudflare:', response.data);

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error response from Cloudflare:', error.response?.data || error.message);
      throw new Error(error.response?.data?.errors[0]?.message || 'Cloudflare deployment failed');
    }
  }

}

export default CloudflareService;

My Clodflare.js file (controller)
import { controller, post } from 'koa-dec-router';
import path from 'path';

@controller('/api/v1/cloudflare')
export default class CloudflareCtrl {
  // POST request to trigger deployment
  @post('/deployment') // Endpoint: /api/v1/cloudflare/deployment
  async deploy(ctx) {
    try {
      const cloudflareService = ctx.resolveService('CloudflareService'); // Resolve the deployment service
      const zipFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../Cloudflare/index.html'); // Replace with the actual ZIP file path

      // Trigger the deployment using the service
      const result = await cloudflareService.deployLocalFile(zipFilePath);

      // Return the result of the deployment
      return ctx.ok({
        message: 'Deployment started successfully!',
        data: result,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any errors during the deployment process
      return ctx.badRequest({
        message: 'Deployment failed',
        error: error.message,
      });
    }
  }

}


